# How to Fix Error 403 Attempting to Access Craft Admin Page Using XAMPP

Tags: server, error

I'm using XAMPP for the very first time and am also new to Craft so any help with this issue would be very much appreciated. I'm attempting to set-up a local dev environment through XAMPP and then be able to make content changes via Craft. I found this set-up guide for MAMP / Craft CMS and have followed it step by step except adapting it for XAMPP:

http://unakravets.tumblr.com/post/58150139083/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-craft

At the end, when I attempt to go to localhost/Craft/public/admin to access the Craft Admin Panel, I get the following message:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

What could be causing this and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Could be a number of things. Here's the obvious ones — check your $craftPath in your public index.php page is pointing to your craft folder; check that your craft/config/db.php has the correct database connection settings (and confirm that you can connect to your DB). Make sure the craft/app, craft/storage, and craft/config folders are writable by php (set to 777 temporarily if you're not sure). Check that you added the '.' to the htaccess file in your public folder. Review the [install page](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing) in the docs to see if you missed anything.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, Douglas! I would have gotten back to you earlier but I didn't realized it had been responded to based on the looking at it in the StackExchange Entry listing. So I can confirm that #craftPath is pointing to the right place, I can connect to the database and that the information is correct in craft/config/db.php, that the folders are writable by PHP and that the htaccess folder was updated appropriately. I'm stumped as to what's going on here. Any other ideas or suggestions?